# Does RISCV SBI refers a hardware implementation or a software standard?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, riscv, instruction-set, supervisor-mode

In the [RISCV SBI](https://github.com/riscv-non-isa/riscv-sbi-doc), there are explanations about supervisor and machine communication. As an example, `A0-A7` registers are filled with Function and extension ID and also return values for SBI functions. I didn't understand that whether those things are done in hardware or software.

I mean when supervisor code fills register for `FID #1 (implementation id)` before `ECALL` instruction, does the machine trap handler control the `A0-A7` registers and return the relevant value after reading `mimpid` by csrr?  Or does hardware look directly the register carrying `FID` and fill the register with `mimpid` without any handler?

If it is the second case, does the core also jump to a handler or does it directly continue to the next instruction with filled registers with the returned SBI function values?

Comment: The hardware executes just the `ecall` instruction itself, which (may) changes privilege and then starts the software exception handler.  The software exception handler looks at `a7` (and other registers) to see what the service request is and what/how to handle that, and then resumes as appropriate.